# LINQ - get results where a certain property is in this other result set of the property's type

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework

I want to find every `BuildingPrice` where the `BuildingPrice.ShedStyle` property will be among the results of `ShedStyles.Where(...)`

```
var prices = db.BuildingPrices.Where(
    p => p.ShedStyle.IsAmong( //There must be some obvious method for this
        db.ShedStyles.Where(s => s.Name.Contains("text")
    );

public class BuildingPrice
{
    public ShedStyle ShedStyle { get; set; }
}
public class ShedStyle
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<BuildingPrice> BuildingPrices { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ShedStyle> ShedStyles { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit late and my brain is not quite at full capacity because I believe this can be done with a Join, but without it, here is what I came up with. You just had this a bit backwards.

```
        var prices = db.BuildingPrices.Where
            (
                p => db.ShedStyles
                    .Where( s => s.Name.Contains("text"))
                    .Contains(p.ShedStyle)

            );
```

Comment: BrokenGlass is correct that querying this directly through the object would be the more expressive approach

Comment: I had only used `Contains` for strings so far and didn't realize it was the inverse of my imaginary `IsAmong` extension - thanks

Answer (score 3):

You *could* do this with `Any()` or `Contains()`:

```
var prices = db.BuildingPrices.Where(
 p => db.ShedStyle.Where(s => s.Name.Contains("text")).Any(x=> x.Name == p.ShedStyle.Name));
```

But given your query why can't you test the condition directly?

```
var prices = db.BuildingPrices.Where(p=> p.ShedStyle.Name.Contains("text"));
```

The latter approach seems much more straightforward.

Comment: I try to make simple examples but sometimes they end up having even easier solutions that bypass the question I'm after :)

Comment: So it seems like `Any` and `Contains` can be used interchangeably sometimes, but w/ Contains you only pass it the object directly instead of the comparer thing.

Answer (score 1):

```
var prices = db.BuildingPrices.Where(
p => db.ShedStyles.Where(s => s.Name.Contains("text")).Contains(p.ShedStyle));
```

Comment: thank you - I was thinking Contains was for strings only - don't know why